# Symfony: Using a type='text' with form type 'checkbox'

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there a way to use the checkbox form type with a field that has been set to string?

This field can hold many values, it can be used to input data as a textfield or as a checkbox.

I have a event listener on the formtype to check if it should be a checkbox or text field.

/Entity.php

```
/**
 * @var string 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
 */
private $value;
```

formtype.php

```
$form->add('value', 'checkbox', array(

))
```

Error

```
Unable to transform value for property path "value": Expected a Boolean.
```

Comment: Lookup data transformers.

Answer (score 6):

Entity.php

```
public function getValue()
{
    return (boolean)$this->value;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

rewrite the function in the Entity, adding explicitly boolean values in returns

```
public function getEstado() {
    if ($this->estado===1) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```